# Mysql cannot login from user account

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, mariadb, freebsd

From `root` user, I can execute this command without any problems:

```
[root@freebsd ~/var/html/www]$ bin/console d:run-sql 'SELECT * from user';
```

From `www` user, I cannot execute this command:

```
[www@freebsd ~/var/html/www]$ bin/console d:run-sql 'SELECT * from user';
```

because I am getting the following error:

```
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied
```

Both users are using the same config file:

```yaml
parameters:
    database_driver: "pdo_mysql"
    database_url: "mysql://dbuser:dbuserpass@127.0.0.1:3306/dbname"
```

I am using MariaDB 10.4 which is running on Freebsd with PHP(Symfony project)

Comment: `user` is a reserved table name(https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqluser-table/), did you try using `dbname.user`?

Comment: It’s a random name, on production the name of the table is different.

Comment: so check the permissions on that table/database for user www

Comment: For login to MySQL on both account I am suing the same MySQL user ‘dbuser’. So this user has permission.

Comment: Does using the mysql shell work? `mysql -u dbuser -p`?

Comment: When I typ `mysql -u dbuser -p` on `www` user, I am getting following error `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock'` BUT when I try this command on `www` user: `mysql -u dbuser -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306`, I can easily login.

Comment: This is because mysql client uses unix socket by default. When you specify "127.0.0.1" the client connects trough TCP. You MySQL server are not listening on unix socket.

Comment: Please share more details - what have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Authentication problems comes with an **access denied** message.

A **permission denied** error means that you authentication happened but the resource you're trying to access was denied. Probably the `dbname` database.

You need to grant at least a "select" permission to this user with root or another administrator user:

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON dbname.* TO dbuser@127.0.0.1;
```

Pay attention because with **mysql** client if we don't specify a host or specify it like `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`, the client tries to connect trought **unix socket**.
You can overcome this with `--protocol tcp` or using a IP address.